# Can Mathematica check if I correctly applied an algebraic transformation?

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, proof

Mathematica has tons of functions to perform [algebraic manipulations](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AlgebraicManipulationOverview.html). But is there a way to use it to *check* if I didn't make mistakes in my own algebraic manipulations.

As a real world example:

- [step1] I have $\sin(\omega t + \pi /2)$
- [step2] I rewrite that as $\sin(\omega t - \pi/4 +3\pi /4)$,
- [step3] I apply a well known identity so I end up with $\sin(\omega t - \pi/4)\cos(3\pi /4) + \cos(\omega t - \pi/4)\sin(3\pi /4)$.

Will Mathematica be able to check:
 $$\text{step1}\Leftrightarrow\text{step2}\Leftrightarrow\text{step3}$$
I don't look for something smart, just verifying I didn't make a sign error or something like that.

Comment: Instead of attempting it by hand, leave the `Cos[a +b]` in your expression, then use [`TrigExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrigExpand.html). E.g. `TrigExpand@Cos[a + b]` returns the identity you sought. See also [`TrigReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrigReduce.html) etc.

Comment: @Marco, I rewrote the question so it may eventually be more clear. For  specific answer to you comment, in [step2], `TrigExpand[Sin[\[Omega] t -a + b]]` will perform a full expansion of the expression, which was not something I wanted.

Comment: `Simplify[step1-step3]`?  Or `FullSimplify`.  When that doesn't work, I plug in random numbers with something like `expr1 - expr2 /. x -> RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 1, WorkingPrecision -> 32]`, depending on what domain I want instead of `{-10, 10}`, how many variables there are, whether the expressions are listable. If listable, it's easy to check 100 random values with `... /. Thread[{x, y, z} -> RandomReal[{-2,2}, {3, 100}, WorkingPrecision -> 32]`.

Comment: Good idea @Michael. I was considering something like that but using `==` instead of a difference. I assume your solution is better suited to deal with rounding errors.

Answer (score 1):

Quickly wrapping up Michael E2's idea:

```
s1 = Sin[w*t + \[Pi]/2];
s2 = Sin[w*t \[Minus] \[Pi]/4 + 3 \[Pi]/4];
s3 = Sin[w*t \[Minus] \[Pi]/4]*Cos[3 \[Pi]/4] + 
   Sin[3 \[Pi]/4]*Cos[w t - \[Pi]/4];
s4 = Sin[w*t + \[Pi]/2.1];

Clear[equal]; 
equal[s1_, s2_, n_ : 100, range_ : {-2, 2}] := Module[{
    vars = Quiet @ Union @ 
           Cases[s3, x_ /; ! ValueQ[x] && Context[x] == "Global`", {-1}, Heads -> True]},
  If[TrigExpand[s1] - TrigExpand[s2] == 0, True,
   tests = Thread[vars -> Table[Slot[i], {i, Length[vars]}]] & @@@ 
     RandomReal[range, {n, Length[vars]}, WorkingPrecision -> 32],
   Thread[s1 /. tests] == Thread[s2 /. tests]
   ]
  ]

equal @@@ {{s1, s2}, {s2, s3}, {s3, s4}}
(* {True, True, False} *)
```