# ReplaceList doesn't apply rules down to subparts

Tags: replacement, expression-manipulation, rule

Somewhat related to [a previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/211344/can-mathematica-check-if-i-correctly-applied-an-algebraic-transformation), I'm experimenting with [ReplaceList](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceList.html) to get the list of all possible transformations we can obtain by applying a rule to an expression. But I don't manage to make it work as expected:

```
expr := 1+Cos[ω t - π/4 + 3π/4]
rule := Cos[a_ + b_] -> X[a,b]
ReplaceList[expr,{ rule }]
```

I expected the result:

```
>     { 1+X[ω t - π/4, 3π/4], 1+X[ω t, -π/4 + 3π/4] }
```

But instead, I obtain:

> ```
> {}
> ```

**Why is Mathematica unable to apply *rule* on *expr*? How should I fix my code to obtain the expected result?**

---

As an extra requirement, I missed the fact that `ReplaceAll` like `Replace` [*"does not map down to subparts"*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html#2276).

I'm probably looking for a mix between `ReplaceList` and [`Cases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html) (?)

---

As per comment, to avoid Mathematica to rewrite the expression as a sinus, I tried wrapping it inside various `Hold*` functions--in no case, the rule is applied.

```
expr := Hold[1+Cos[ω t - π/4 + 3π/4]]
```

```
expr := HoldForm[1+Cos[ω t - π/4 + 3π/4]]
```

```
expr := HoldComplete[1+Cos[ω t - π/4 + 3π/4]]
```

Comment: because mathematica automatically rewrites expr as `Sin[t \[Omega]]`

Comment: Because `expr` evaluates to `-Sin[t ω]`, which does not contain any expression with `Cos` head, so nothing in it matches the left-hand side of your rule? I also find your `rule` definition using `SetDelayed` somewhat odd, so I wonder whether there might not be a misunderstanding there. Why should it matter that `rule` is evaluated every time it is called?

Comment: Thanks both of you for the comments. @Nasser, I tried wrapping the expression definition in `Hold`, `HoldForm` and `HoldComplete`. It prevents rewriting the expression as as sinus--but the rule still doesn't apply.

Comment: @Marco  _"I also find your rule definition using `SetDelayed` somewhat odd, so I wonder whether there might not be a misunderstanding there."_ Indeed. What would be the consequences of using `SetDelayed` instead of `Set`?

Comment: @Sylvain I think you might want `RuleDelayed` (`:>`) rather than `SetDelayed`, i.e. you would want to delay the evaluation of the right-hand side of the rule until `a` and `b` have been given values. I have put the rest in an answer cause it was getting too long for comments.

Comment: @Marco Yes. I made a confusion between `:= ... -> ...` and `= ... :> ....`

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead

```
expr := Hold[Cos[ω t - π/4 + 3 π/4]]
rule := Cos[a_ + b_] :> X[a, b]
ReleaseHold[ReplaceAll[expr, {rule}]]
```

> ```
> X[t ω, π/2]
> ```

In reply to the comment

```
expr := Hold[Cos[ω t - π/4 + 3 π/4]]
rule := Cos[a_] :> (a /. List -> X)
ReleaseHold[ReplaceAll[expr /. Plus -> List, {rule}]]
```

> ```
> X[t ω, -(π/4), (3 π)/4]
> ```

I'm sure there is a simpler way.

Comment: Thanks, @Chris. Is there a way to prevent `- π/4 + 3 π/4` to be reduced to `-π/2`?

Comment: I failed to notice that `ReplaceAll` does not apply to subparts. I've edited the question accordingly. Sorry @Chris for having wasted your time.

Answer (score 2):

As discussed in comments, you have to somehow prevent MMA from rewriting your `Cos` expression, which you can accomplish with a `Hold` function. I am still not sure that I understand the intended outcome, but I wonder if this is what you are after:

```
Clear[expr, rule]
expr = HoldForm@Cos[ω t - π/4 + 3 π/4]
rule = HoldForm@Cos[a_ + b_] :> X[a, b]
ReplaceList[expr, rule]

(* Out: 
{X[t ω, π/2], X[-(π/4), (3 π)/4 + t ω], 
 X[(3 π)/4, -(π/4) + t ω], 
 X[-(π/4) + t ω, (3 π)/4], 
 X[(3 π)/4 + t ω, -(π/4)], X[π/2, t ω]}
*)
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for. One question though: why in another answer given by @ChrisDegnen he has to use `ReleaseHold` whereas you don't need it? I also notice in his answer `- π/4 + 3 π/4` was replaced by `-π/2` (something I _don't_ want). Is that related to `ReleaseHold`?

Comment: Ouch: I failed to notice that `ReplaceAll` does not apply to subparts. I've edited the question accordingly. Sorry for having wasted your time.

Answer (score 1):

You may be trying to solve the wrong problem.  It is better to define a rule that applies to all the forms in which your expression might appear.  For example

```
expr = Cos[ω t - π/4 + (3 π)/4]
(* -Sin[t ω] *)

rule = {Cos[a_ + b_.] -> X[a, b], Sin[a_ + b_.] -> X[a, -(π/2) + b]};

expr /. rule
(* -X[t ω, -(π/2)] *)
```

Comment: Thnaks @mikado. I don't have checked your answer yet--but I wanted to warn you ASAP I've edited the question because I failed to notice initially `Replace` was not replacing down to subexpressions. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this approach is more in keeping with your coding style.

```
expr = Inactivate[1 + Cos[ω t - π/4 + 3 π/4], Cos]
rule = Inactive[Cos][Plus[args__]] -> X[args]
ReplaceAll[expr, rule]
```

> `1 + X[π/2 + t ω]`

Notes

- Personally, I prefer the short form

  ```
  expr /. rule
  ```

  to using `ReplaceAll`.
- The revised rule you see above was written after I inspected

  ```
  expr // FullForm
  ```

  > `Plus[1, Inactive[Cos][Plus[Times[Rational[1, 2], Pi], Times[t, ω]]]]`